# UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState crash only iOS13

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios13

crash only iOS13，But I don't know where it came from
I think it's the same problem and hope to help me
My code has UI update code, but I'm not sure what caused it. Please help me

```html
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration animations:^{
        if (fullScreenMode) {
            self.topBarTop.constant = -(self.topBarHeight.constant);
            self.bottomBarBottom.constant = -(self.bottomBarHeight.constant);
        }
        else {
            self.topBarTop.constant = 0;
            self.bottomBarBottom.constant = 0;
        }
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            [FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"setFullScreenMode_finished" parameters:nil];
        }
    }];
```

log 1:

```html
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  UIKitCore                      0x19aaa908c +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 92
1  UIKitCore                      0x19aad9424 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 648
2  UIKitCore                      0x19aad99b0 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:] + 108
3  UIKitCore                      0x19aaa48f0 __50-[UITransitionView _startTransition:withDuration:]_block_invoke.169 + 76
4  UIKitCore                      0x19aad9f74 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) conditionallyAnimate:withAnimation:layout:completion:] + 88
5  UIKitCore                      0x19aaa4510 -[UITransitionView _startTransition:withDuration:] + 616
6  UIKitCore                      0x19aaa3fac -[UITransitionView transition:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 2368
7  UIKitCore                      0x19a071d94 -[UIViewControllerBuiltinTransitionViewAnimator animateTransition:] + 1484
8  UIKitCore                      0x19a0799d4 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke_2 + 56
9  UIKitCore                      0x19a186070 +[UIInputResponderController _pinInputViewsForInputResponderController:onBehalfOfResponder:duringBlock:] + 104
10 UIKitCore                      0x19a079964 ___UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition_block_invoke.645 + 176
11 UIKitCore                      0x19aad79c0 +[UIView(Animation) _setAlongsideAnimations:toRunByEndOfBlock:] + 172
12 UIKitCore                      0x19a0797cc _UIViewControllerTransitioningRunCustomTransition + 580
13 UIKitCore                      0x199f71bf4 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke.467 + 2348
14 UIKitCore                      0x19a663b98 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 316
15 UIKitCore                      0x19a6537c0 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 232
16 UIKitCore                      0x19a683594 _afterCACommitHandler + 76
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1965c9c48 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1965c4b34 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 416
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1965c5100 __CFRunLoopRun + 1308
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1965c48bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
21 GraphicsServices               0x1a0430328 GSEventRunModal + 104
22 UIKitCore                      0x19a65a6d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
23 WebComics                      0x10266e51c main + 14 (main.m:14)
24 libdyld.dylib                  0x19644f460 <redacted> + 4
```